# XSLT - Applying multiple templates to the same element

Tags: xslt

Right now I'm using a replace template which converts `<p></p>` tags in a new line:

```
<xsl:template name="string-replace">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="replace" />
    <xsl:param name="by" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$text = '' or $replace = ''or not($replace)" >
            <!-- Prevent this routine from hanging -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
            <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
                <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I use it like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="replaceString">
    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$data/description/text" />
        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'&#xa;'" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

The thing is that the client now requested that other HTML tags should be interpreted correctly. For example, I want to replace `<br>`, or to set the font to bold when I have something like `<b>Hello</b>` inside the text.

For the `<br>` replacement I wrote this snippet:

```
<xsl:template match="br">
    <fo:block></fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

And for the `<b>` replacement this one:

```
<xsl:template match="b">
    <fo:inline font-weight="bold">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
    </fo:inline>
</xsl:template>
```

How can I apply multiple transformations to the same text?

A text sample might look like this: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nisl neque, lobortis ac consequat eu, feugiat a erat. Morbi eget augue dolor. Pellentesque vel laoreet ex. <p></p>Quisque convallis nisl tellus, in rhoncus libero porttitor in. Cras nunc diam, condimentum in ornare ut, mattis in arcu. Nulla ultrices sapien ligula, vel volutpat risus pharetra sed. <br></b>Nunc quis arcu eu ex <b>cursus pellentesque</b> at eget augue.`. So it's a string with markup, not an XML with `p` or `b` elements.

Comment: Some of your code seems to match elements and transform them while that named template seems to try to process plain text. It is not clear to me what kind of input you have, is that an XML document with `p` and `br` and `b` elements or do you have a string with markup?

Comment: Hey, Martin. I have a string with markup.

Comment: Your question is confusing - please post a [mcve], including the expected output.

Comment: But in that case I don't understand why your templates with `match` would do anything. You might want to tell us which XSLT processor you use and show us minimal but complete samples, as already requested.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, so basically `<xsl:template match="b">` will only match a `<b>` tag if it's an XML element, right?

Comment: You will need to check whether your XSLT processor supports something like https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-parse-xml-fragment to turn the string with markup into nodes. You can only use template matching with `match="b"` on element nodes you either get from an input document passed to the XSLT processor or you parse from a string.

Comment: ... or from an input document parsed via the `document()` function from a file identified by an external URI.